# Why low results with Content-Based recommendation?

Tags: recommender-system, cosine-similarity, tf-idf

I'm unable to get a good result with my Content-Based recommendation (very low Precision)

Items are different sort of services (Yelp DataSet).

To compute the item's profiles, I used a classical approach with TF-IDF. Where each item has a number of attribute, and TF-IDF gives the weight of the attribute in the item.

To learn the user profile, I perform a simple average of item's profiles previousely rated by the user.

To compute similarity between user profile and item profile, I used the Cosine similarity.

The recommendation result is a simple Top-K list, where I vary the value of K to analyze the different values of Recall/Precision.

The problem is that I get alaways a bad Precision.

1- I want to know if it is normal to get bad result of Precision with my method.

2- I want to know if the dataSet could be the origin of the problem ?

3- Is there a more sophisticated method to learn the user profile ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is still unclear as it is not at all clear what you are trying to do, what data you have and so on.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have Yelp DataSet.
And I have mentioned that I want to realize a content-based recommendation.